# Gradle installation gives different gradle version

Tags: java, spring, unix, gradle

As a new user I am trying to install gradle-5.6.4 on my mac but when I check gradle version it shows Gradle 7.0. Is there anything to switch or correct the versioning to gradle.

```
machine1:~ user$ cd /Users/user/Downloads/gradle-5.6.4/bin 
machine1:bin user$ gradle

Welcome to Gradle 7.0!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - File system watching enabled by default
 - Support for running with and building Java 16 projects
 - Dependency catalog feature preview

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/release-notes.html
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
> Task :help
Welcome to Gradle 7.0.
To run a build, run gradle <task> ...
To see a list of available tasks, run gradle tasks
To see a list of command-line options, run gradle --help
To see more detail about a task, run gradle help --task <task>
For troubleshooting, visit https://help.gradle.org
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 6s
1 actionable task: 1 executed

machine1:bin user$ 
machine1:bin user$ gradle wrapper --gradle-version 5.6.4
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
> Task :wrapper FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':wrapper' (type 'Wrapper').
  - Type 'Wrapper' property 'jarFile' is not writable because '/Users/user/Downloads/gradle-5.6.4/bin/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar' ancestor '/Users/user/Downloads/gradle-5.6.4/bin/gradle' is not a directory.
    
    Reason: Cannot write a file to a location pointing at a directory.
    
    Possible solution: Configure 'jarFile' to point to a file, not a directory.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/validation_problems.html#cannot_write_output for more details about this problem.
  - Type 'Wrapper' property 'propertiesFile' is not writable because '/Users/user/Downloads/gradle-5.6.4/bin/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties' ancestor '/Users/user/Downloads/gradle-5.6.4/bin/gradle' is not a directory.
    
    Reason: Cannot write a file to a location pointing at a directory. 
    Possible solution: Configure 'propertiesFile' to point to a file, not a directory.
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/validation_problems.html#cannot_write_output for more details about this problem.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
machine1:bin user$ 
machine1:bin user$ 
machine1:bin user$ ./gradlew build
-bash: ./gradlew: No such file or directory
machine1:bin user$ pwd
/Users/user/Downloads/gradle-5.6.4/bin
machine1:bin user$ ls
gradle      gradle.bat  settings.gradle
```

Not sure if Gradle 7 have been accidentally installed and overwrite to gradle 5.6.4. Not sure of what are the right steps to follow.  In my .bash_profile I have added below :

```
export GRADLE_HOME=/Users/user/Downloads/gradle-5.6.4
export PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin
```

Also there is .gradle folder which gets generated and shows > .gradle.caches>7.0 in folder, if that points to Gradle 7.0. I have tried to delete this also but get auto generated.

Comment: You are adding this to the end of your PATH environment variable, so it will be found last. Is there another Gradle folder already in PATH?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't in a project directory when you are running those commands.

Run the gradle command from within your project folder, not the bin folder of a Gradle installation.

Check the value of your PATH environment variable to see what other Gradle installations might already be part of it.

```
echo $PATH
```

I'm fairly certain you will find that the gradle command of Gradle 7.0 is already on the path.  You can edit the PATH or provide the full path to invoke Gradle 5.6.4, but the best thing to do is to use the Gradle wrapper in your project to force the Gradle version to what you know works for your project.

Note that 'gradlew' is not part of Gradle, it is a wrapper script added to some individual Gradle-based projects.